# Why sshfs does not work with backtick?

Tags: ruby, system-calls, backticks

When I do the following:

```
`sshfs my@host.com /tmp/dir1/`
```

in a irb console, the console freezes.

If I use something like system("sshfs my@host.com /tmp/dir1/") it works, but I need to use backticks because the system call is in a method used many times, and some of them need the return from the shell.

Any tip?

Comment: "console" is some ruby console?

Usually, "console" is used to mean a terminal with some shell like bash/ksh/tcsh/zsh.

Comment: could you comment on why there is a ruby tag??

Comment: Because it is in a ruby console (irb)

Answer (score 1):

I think @host might be getting interpolated.